# Pandoc performs very slowly when referencing large biblatex file

Tags: pandoc, bibtex, biblatex

Whenever I have a pandoc markdown file that I am converting to PDF or HTML, and it contains a reference to a large biblatex file (> 100 KB) for citations, the performance is incredibly slow. I end up needing to convert directly to `tex` first and then running regular latex commands, *e.g.* `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `pdflatex`.

For example, if I have two files `refs.bib` and `test.md`, this following command takes forever to run;

`pandoc test.md -o test.pdf --bibliography refs.bib`

or

`pandoc test.md -o test.html --bibliography refs.bib`

My current workaround is to instead to export to `latex` and then run `latex` commands directly:

```
pandoc test.md -o test.tex --bibliography refs.bib
latex test.tex
bibtex test.aux
latex test.tex
pdflatex test
```

What is going on with the performance of using pandoc? My understanding was that essentially these were the same calls going on in the background.

I have created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/stanley-gu/2017894222d42324bef1) that contains the test files.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the slowdown is due to the fact that pandoc has to call citeproc-hs, which has to call bibutils, which has to convert the entire bibtex file to the native citeproc format.

The easiest way to speed things up, at the moment, is to write a script that extracts the relevant bibtex entries to a temporary file, and runs pandoc against that. This [thread on the pandoc-discuss mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/pandoc-discuss/p156lTJFjuk) includes links to some scripts that do this:

- https://gist.github.com/dsanson/1383132
- https://github.com/reagle/pandoc-wrappers/blob/master/md2bib.py